# JPA metamodel fields are null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpamodelgen

I have some JPA classes and generate metamodel through `org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor`. So, one of my classes is:

```
@Table(name = "USER")
@Entity
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "User.byLogin", query = "select u from User u where u.login = :login and u.active = :active")})
public class User implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "ID")
  @Id
  private Long id;
  @Column(name = "LOGIN")
  private String login;
  @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
  private Boolean active;
  // etc..
}
```

Metamodel processor generates this:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(User.class)
public abstract class User_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, Long> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, Boolean> active;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, String> login;

}
```

Then, there is the following code in my business logic classes:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put(User_.login.getName(), username);
params.put(User_.active.getName(), Boolean.TRUE);
userDao.executeNamedQuery("User.byLogin", params);
```

This code crashes with NPE on at the second line. I noticed through debugger that `User_` fields are all `null`. So, the question is: is there a way to initialize these fields? How can i do that?

P.S. This is a legacy code, it worked fine for long time, but now it seems to be broken somehow.

Comment: JPA metamodel is meant to be used only in Criteria queries as explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjrij.html). I am not sure whether it can be used in the parameters construction of a named query at all. Also note that the usage is completely different from yours

Comment: @perissf i understand. The only thing i dont understand is that it worked somehow before. So there are big amounts of similar legacy code, and i wonder if there a way to fix it without rewriting all of that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static Metamodel attributes null when unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36225377/static-metamodel-attributes-null-when-unit-testing)

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans Sorry, I cannot confirm - I don't work with JPA anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter values of JPA metamodel are supposed to be null. From what I get it is impossible to get string containing name from `User_.login.getName()` because `User_.login` does not exist (is never initialized). `User_` is an abstract class, and those values cannot be initialized. The only way to get variable names from metamodel is to get all of them. I'm using following program

```
public class EntityReader {
    public static<T> String[] getArguments(Class<T> classToRead){
        Field[] fields = classToRead.getFields();
        String[] result = new String[fields.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) result[i] = fields[i].getName();
        return result;
    }
}
```